# diacritics in asp.net querystring collection

Tags: asp.net, diacritics, request.querystring

I'm trying to get a value out of the querystring that has diacritics. The diacritics are encoded in utf-8 %uxxx format, and when I check Request.QueryString["name"] they are incorrectly decoded. However, if i check Request.RawUrl, they are there and correct.

I've tried adding

<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>

but still have the issue.

Is there any solution to this issue short of parsing the RawUrl myself and correctly handling the diacritics?

Comment: For the benefit of others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic